# Calculating elapsed time for different interview dates in R

Tags: r, reshape, date-arithmetic

So my data looks like this

```
dat<-data.frame(
subjid=c("a","a","a","b","b","c","c","d","e"),
type=c("baseline","first","second","baseline","first","baseline","first","baseline","baseline"),
date=c("2013-02-07","2013-02-27","2013-04-30","2013-03-03","2013-05-23","2013-01-02","2013-07-23","2013-03-29","2013-06-03"))
```

i.e)

```
  subjid     type       date
1      a baseline 2013-02-07
2      a    first 2013-02-27
3      a   second 2013-04-30
4      b baseline 2013-03-03
5      b    first 2013-05-23
6      c baseline 2013-01-02
7      c    first 2013-07-23
8      d baseline 2013-03-29
9      e baseline 2013-06-03
```

and I'm trying to make a variable "elapsedtime" that denotes the time elapsed from the baseline date to first and second round interview dates (so that elapsedtime=0 for baselines). Note that it varies individually whether they have taken further interviews.

I tried to reshape the data so that I could subtract each dates but my brain isn't really functioning today--or is there another way?

Please help and thank you.

Comment: `dat$elapsed <- unlist(by(as.Date(dat$date), dat$subjid, function(i)  i-i[1]))` is one way

Comment: To continue your approach, I assume by "reshaping" you got something like `reshape(dat, direction = "wide", idvar = "subjid", timevar = "type")`? Then, you could just subtract (assuming "date" is converted to `as.Date`) the respective columns, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screaming out for `ave`:

I'll throw an `NA` value in there just for good measure:

```
dat<-data.frame(
subjid=c("a","a","a","b","b","c","c","d","e"),
type=c("baseline","first","second","baseline","first","baseline","first","baseline","baseline"),
date=c("2013-02-07","NA","2013-04-30","2013-03-03","2013-05-23","2013-01-02","2013-07-23","2013-03-29","2013-06-03"))
```

And you should probably sort the data to be on the safe side:

```
dat$type <- ordered(dat$type,levels=c("baseline","first","second","third") )
dat <- dat[order(dat$subjid,dat$type),]
```

Turn your date into a proper `Date` object:

```
dat$date <- as.Date(dat$date)
```

Then calculate the differences:

```
dat$elapsed <- ave(as.numeric(dat$date),dat$subjid,FUN=function(x) x-x[1] )

#  subjid     type       date  elapsed
#1      a baseline 2013-02-07        0
#2      a    first       <NA>       NA
#3      a   second 2013-04-30       82
#4      b baseline 2013-03-03        0
#5      b    first 2013-05-23       81
#6      c baseline 2013-01-02        0
#7      c    first 2013-07-23      202
#8      d baseline 2013-03-29        0
#9      e baseline 2013-06-03        0
```

Comment: Will `baseline` always be in position 1 of a subset?

Comment: I actually have some NA's in the data (e.g. NA in subject a's first interview date) and it causes "elapsed" to be also NA for his second interview date. Would you please comment on this?

Comment: @user3038380 - ah... I noticed a little error in my method. You were wanting the time from the baseline always, not the difference from one interview to another. The new code will handle NAs better.

Answer (score 1):

This makes no assumptions that `baseline` is the always at position `1`:

```
dat$date <- as.Date(dat$date)
dat$elapesed <- unlist(by(dat, dat$subjid, FUN=function(x) {
  as.numeric(x$date - x[x$type=="baseline",]$date)
}))
```

Comment: ... and this method assumes that subjid's are always grouped together. Try rearranging the data `dat <- dat[sample(1:9),]` and re-running it. It's probably good general advice to sort data first with these sorts of operations, and I will add that to my answer.

Comment: yes the data is sorted such that baseline is always in position 1 for each subjects.